# Flutter - How add separators fot BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use BottomNavigationBar in my flutter app. This is exist view:

[image]

but I need to add separators between items. like this:

[image]

Is it possible? is there a simple way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible using `BottomAppBar` by having `Container` as a child to specify custom `height` of the appbar and then it can have `Row` to add children. The `Row` can have 3 `FlatButtons`, each having an `Icon` and `Text` inside a `Column`. Between each `FlatButton`, you can add `Container` to add divider. Below is code snippet:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.home),
                  Text('Home')
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.black, width: 2,),
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.business),
                  Text('Business')
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.black, width: 2,),
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.school),
                  Text('School')
                ],
              ),
            )
          ]
        ),
        )
      ),
```

And the output :

[image]